# Are there any SSDs and hard drives available with “Respects Your Freedom” firmware?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, firmware

Is any hard drive sold with “[Respects your Freedom](https://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/endorsement/respects-your-freedom)” firmware? Last time I checked, I couldn't find any around.

However, I noticed that, even though the “Respects Your Freedom” certification doesn't list any specifically, they do list a few laptops which do come with hard drive storage, and one wonders whether these might possibly be devices that they themselves are “Respects Your Freedom” certified.

With respect to SSD drives, is [OpenSSD](http://www.openssd-project.org/wiki/The_OpenSSD_Project) the only project providing “Respects Your Freedom” firmware?

Answer (score 0):

The “Respects Your Freedom” certification program is managed by the [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/) and the focus is clearly on higher level system concerns; stuff above the firmware level.

Checking the official page for “[Respects Your Freedom hardware certification requirements](https://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/endorsement/criteria)” it states the following regarding components; bold emphasis is mine:

> However, there is an exception for secondary embedded processors. **The exception applies to software delivered inside auxiliary and low-level processors and FPGAs, within which software installation is not intended after the user obtains the product. This can include, for instance, microcode inside a processor, firmware built into an I/O device, or the gate pattern of an FPGA.** The software in such secondary processors does not count as product software.

Meaning to be completely reasonable, it seems that a while a system or device can be “Respects Your Freedom” certified, it can still contain components that don’t necessarily allow easy user software modification such as SSD firmware.

And yes, OpenSSD exists. But I see that as something akin to [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com) router firmware; something where you can buy the router with manufacturer installed and supported firmware but then can flash it after purchase to Tomato or DD-WRT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any other project similar to OpenSSD, or any analogue for HDD?

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t follow such things. If you found my answer helpful, please be sure top upvote it. And if it’s the answer that provided an answer your question, please be sure to check it off as the answer.